# How to bring a Text vertically center using Flex CSS for bar chart

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to show the amount text as vertically horizontal just like Mozilla developer page shows for browser support but using flex CSS eg. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform   (check in bottom of the page)

I have tried the flex CSS almost I have achieved it, but the text is breaking and its not center and bottom end align.

**CSS**

```
ul.chart-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

ul li.container:nth-child(1) {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.skills {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    animation: draw 1s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.amount {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    color: #9c9c9c;
    font-family: "sans-serif";
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    animation: amountVal 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

trying to bring the amount text in vertical alignment using flex for bar chart, but its breaking

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snx5mqj8/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changes some CSS property to perform text center

I removed `transform-origin` property in `amount` class and replace `align-items: flex-end;` with `center` in `skill` class and add `white-space` CSS property to see amount and text in one line

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/df6uraLw

Comment: amount to be touched to bottom line and the amount should be in one line

Comment: @NishargShah if you change `align-items: end` to `align-items: center`, it works as the OP wants.

Comment: yes, i know `writing-mode` is new CSS property that currently in trending but he used rotate for that, so for that i dont want to change it @AdityaThakur

Comment: @AdityaThakur If someone flag your comment, moderator will punish you for that because this type of word is not granted in SO, so delete it

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to look exactly like the one in mozilla you'll need writing-mode and absolute positioning, here i did it without flexbox, using `writing-mode` and `position:absolute`, it aligns really well, see if it works for you https://jsfiddle.net/k6gcxysr/

```
.skills {
  padding: 0;
  width:100%;
  animation: draw 1s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
}
.amount {
    color: #9c9c9c;
    font-family: "sans-serif";
    animation: amountVal 2s ease-in-out; 
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    position:absolute;
    right:30%;
    bottom:4%;
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
    }
```

Comment: In question he mentioned about flex so for that i continued to use `flexbox`

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct, should i keep it or remove it?

Comment: Dont, you done with another CSS property and it helps someone in future, so dont delete it and +1 for appreciation